# Unity3D - Raycast returns nothing in console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a gun system and I've created a pistol.

```
public class Gun : MonoBehaviour {

[Header("References")]
[SerializeField] private GunData gunData;
[SerializeField] private Transform cam;

float timeSinceLastShot;

private void Start() {
    PlayerShoot.shootInput += Shoot;
    PlayerShoot.reloadInput += StartReload;
}

private void OnDisable() => gunData.reloading = false;

public void StartReload() {
    if (!gunData.reloading && this.gameObject.activeSelf)
        StartCoroutine(Reload());
}

private IEnumerator Reload() {
    gunData.reloading = true;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(gunData.reloadTime);

    gunData.currentAmmo = gunData.magSize;

    gunData.reloading = false;
}

private bool CanShoot() => !gunData.reloading && timeSinceLastShot > 1f / (gunData.fireRate / 60f);

private void Shoot() {
    if (gunData.currentAmmo > 0) {
        if (CanShoot()) {
            if (Physics.Raycast(cam.position, cam.forward, out RaycastHit hitInfo, gunData.maxDistance)){
                Debug.Log(hitInfo.transform.name);
                Poskodovani damageable = hitInfo.transform.GetComponent<Poskodovani>();
                damageable?.TakeDamage(gunData.damage);
            }
            else {
                Debug.Log("Nista");
            }

            gunData.currentAmmo--;
            timeSinceLastShot = 0;
            OnGunShot();
        }
    }
}

private void Update() {
    timeSinceLastShot += Time.deltaTime;

    Debug.DrawRay(cam.position, cam.forward * gunData.maxDistance);
}

private void OnGunShot() { }
```

}

As you can see, the Raycast should return the object name on hit or return "Nista" on hitting nothing. I also drew the raycast and it's working fine and shows as it should. I want it to return the object name in the console but it's just nothing. Also, the Gun Data file that I've created for gun info works and shows my ammo going down.

Comment: Does your object has a Rigidbody? It is required for the Raycast to hit.